# Как получить внешний ip адрес компьютера?

Tags: java, ip

Можно ли  получить  **внешний ip адрес средствами java?**

или

Как получить **внешний IP через сервис WhoIs?**

---

**Желательно кроссплатформенное решение.**

(есть: сервер под линукс... клиенты под Windows [не все на java])

Рассматривается простой случай, когда сервер и клиенты на разных  компьютерах соединены через интернет (в локальной сети все олтично работает)

**proxy** не используется

**NAT**   не используется

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939218/getting-the-external-ip-address-in-java

Comment: Машина какая (что за Ось?)? За натом?

Comment: @Suvitruf, я добавил описание в вопрос

Comment: Из Java для линукса я знаю как, так как там ip внешний в интерфейсах сети есть. На Винде не знаю, будет ли работать норм )

Comment: Java это кроссплатформа должно работать и там. Либо вы можете дополнить свой вопрос. Я вам дал исчерпывающий ответ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, в консоли Linux / UNIX можно применить утилиты curl и wget и получить IP через http запрос

curl ifconfig.me

или:

curl smart-ip.net/myip

Эта команда выведет вам в консоль IP-адрес, с которого вы видны внешнему миру.

Аналогичной задаче может послужить и утилита wget:

wget -O - -q icanhazip.com

или:

wget -O - -q ifconfig.me/ip

Существуют и другие, более длинные варианты:

lynx --source http://formyip.com/ | awk '/The/{print $5}'
wget -q -O - http://formyip.com/ | awk '/The/{print $5}'
wget -q -O - http://checkip.dyndns.com/ | awk '{print $6}' | sed 's/<.*>//'

Эти решения для определения внешнего IP-адреса удобно использовать на хостах без графического веб-браузера и в скриптах командной оболочки, например:

```
#!/bin/bash

MYIP=$(wget -O - -q icanhazip.com);
echo $MYIP;
```

А вот пример на Java

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

URL whatismyip = new URL("http://checkip.amazonaws.com");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                whatismyip.openStream()));

String ip = in.readLine(); //you get the IP as a String
System.out.println(ip);
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А можно ли получить IP без обращения к какому-либо ресурсу?

Comment: ну если кабель напрямую подключен к вашему пк, то можно. Посмотрите интерфейсы.